# Truncated features in a feature layer(hosted) still consumes database storage space in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I have a feature layer hosted in AGOL, it had 333 records and used 18MB of DB storage in ArcGIS Online. I then removed all the features using Truncate. It still shows me the same storage space even there are no features.
[image: enter image deStorage Spacescription here]

Comment: Search on the term "high water mark" in the context of databases. Note that DELETE and TRUNCATE are different operations, so your question title and body disagree.

Comment: With AGOL, the layer's size as given on the Overview page seems to be tied to the service definition or whatever file was uploaded to create the layer. For instance, my department has a workflow layer that, when uploaded originally, was less than 1MB. It has since grown by over 10x the number of records, and yet the Overview page still shows it as being the exact same size. If you update the underlying SD / file, it will update that piece of information.